Module for Library classes with Angular 17
In the "domain" layer, usually I have classes like:

Entity type
Entity Service
Entity Mapper
Entity Store

In the "view/feature" layer I need only the Entity and Store classes so I'd like to keep hidden the Service and Mapper in the library. Ie. not publicate with index.ts.
On the other hand the Entity Service should be registered as provider.
How can I define providers in a library and then use them in other library all these dependencies configured?
In general, how can I use a Module in a library, defined in another library with standalone component?


how can I use a Module in a library, defined in another library with standalone component

Just import it.

How can I define providers in a library and then use them in other library all these dependencies configured

Export a module configuring them, and import this module into your standalone components / NG modules.
